# $L^1$ norm of oscillatory integral operator

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, asymptotics, norms

My question is about the $L^1_x$ norm of an oscillatory integral like 
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i(y\cdot x+\lambda \phi(y))}f(y)dy,$$ where $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, $f\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is compactly supported and $\phi$ is real-valued and smooth (I have in mind $\phi(y)=\sqrt{1+|y|^2}$ but feel free to assume what you need). Of course, I am interested in the decay rate for $\lambda$ in this norm. Is there any known result or some hint?

The classical $L^{\infty}$ van der Corput bound is too "strong" to be integrated and I already used Bernstein-type lemmas, but I would like to have a refined estimate if any. I tried to look for results in this area following the traces of the classical papers by Hormander and Phong-Stein on $L^p \to L^{p'}$ boundedness, but nothing useful came out.‌

Comment: Just a stupid question. If $\phi(y)$ is constant on $supp(f)$, the norm you are looking at does not depend on $\lambda$ at all (the Fourier transform just gets shifted), so you need to impose some non-degeneracy condition on the differential of $\phi$ to get any decay. What would that be? (or what is your $\phi$ really?)

Comment: In fact I have in mind $\phi(y) = \sqrt{1+y^2}$, but the general problem of giving suitable conditions on $\phi$ for bounding the $L^1$ norm seems worthy of interest too.

Comment: Erm.. Is $\lambda$ a vector then?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the typo!

Comment: You know well that for typical real nonstationary phases the pointwise decay is arbitrarily fast and for degenerate phases (with finite order) it is algebraically fast. However, already the $L^2$ norm of the integral does not decay, by Plancherel. Thus I expect the $L^1$ norm to actually grow in $\lambda$.

Comment: @PieroD'Ancona In other words, you say that once we have a uniform $L^\infty$ bound (obvious) and the $L^2$-norm is preserved (Plancherel), at the very least we have a fixed bound from below and if we can get any decaying bound on the $L^\infty$-norm, then the $L^1$ norm will tend to $\infty$. Clever! The pointwise decay argument is not so convincing because the bulk of the transform may be moving with $\lambda$ (say, when $\phi$ is linear, then we just have a shift).

Comment: Sure, my argument was mostly heuristics, but maybe with some work it can be turned into a proof

Comment: Thanks @Piero, I think I can see the heuristics behind your comment, I'll try to work out the details. So, what can be said about the growth in $\lambda$? The $\lambda^{n/2}$ from a Bernstein-type estimate is the best we can hope for?